# ASP.Net MVC Bundles and Minification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When moving from development to a production environment I have run into some problems with the way in which my javascript files are being minified.  It seems that some do not minify properly, and so I have been looking around to find a way to not minify a specific bundle.

```
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection _bundles)
    {
        _bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/toNotMinify").Include(
            "~/Scripts/xxxxxx.js"
            ));

        _bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/toMinify").Include(
            "~/Scripts/yyyyy.js"
            ));
        etc..
```

This is the basic layout in my bundle config class.  I want to find a way in which to have all of my bundles minified, apart from the first one.  Is this possible?  So far the only solution I have found to achieve something similar is to turn off minification globally.

Answer (score 13):

You have a couple of options, you can either replace your use of `ScriptBundle` with `Bundle` as in this example:

```
_bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/toNotMinify").Include(
    "~/Scripts/xxxxxx.js"
));
```

.. or you could disable all transformations on a newly created bundle, like so:

```
var noMinify = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/toNotMinify").Include(
    "~/Scripts/xxxxxx.js"
);
noMinify.Transforms.Clear();
_bundles.Add(noMinify);
```

Obviously the first solution is much prettier :)

Comment: Rudy Sorry! I edited your response by mistake instead of mine (I left some code out by mistake and pressed on "edit" to change it. My bad ;(

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried both these methods, but it still seems to minify it down when building in release mode for some reason

Comment: Rudis soln should work.  If you construct a basic Bundle without specifying any transform, it will simply bundle the files as is, so this definitely should not minify your bundle.

Comment: for file 'x.js' in the bundle ensure that there is NOT a 'x.min.js' file in the folder

Comment: @stooboo why not? A normal Bundle will only include what it is given.

Comment: you're right for Bundle .. but for ScriptBundle we found that even after 'Clear'ing the transforms it still picked up the x.min.js file if it existed in the filesystem :-(

Comment: With the basic bundle (first snippet), how do you output it on the view? `@Bundle.Render("~/bundles/toNotMinify")`, `@Bundles.Render("~/bundles/toNotMinify")` and `@Bundle("~/bundles/toNotMinify")` all don't work.

Comment: @Koveras the same was as every bundle. `@Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/Bundle")`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to declare a generic Bundle object and specify the transforms you need:

```
var dontMinify = new Bundle("~/bundles/toNotMinify").Include(
                                        "~/Scripts/xxxxx.js");
            bundles.Add(dontMinify);

            var minify = new Bundle("~/bundles/toNotMinify").Include(
                "~/Scripts/yyyyyy.js");
            minify.Transforms.Add(new JsMinify());
            bundles.Add(minify);
```