# How can I use bundling with TinyMCE?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, tinymce, bundling-and-minification

Internet Explorer has a fit when I try and render the minified TinyMCE bundle. So, in order to create a bundle that avoids minification, I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14816313/1015595) to set up a "generic" or "basic" bundle in my BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add( new Bundle( "~/Scripts/tinymce" )
                 .Include( "~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
                            "~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js" ) );
```

How do I render this on the page? None of the following seem to work:

```
@Bundles.Render( "~/Scripts/tinymce" )
@Bundle.Render( "~/Scripts/tinymce" )
@Bundle( "~/Scripts/tinymce" )
```

This renders the tag at least:

```
@Scripts.Render( "~/Scripts/tinymce" )
```

But it throws a 403 error when it tries to load the file:

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:1062/Scripts/tinymce/?v=MTojK5ORvAZmonNqNGJ3aWhOYyor-Fa8dZHTqfSOlUM1"
```

Comment: This has been answered [in this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15555201/1810243). You can't give your bundle a name that is also the name of an existing directory.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out in the comments, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555201/1810243) addresses part of the issue. Since you can't give your bundle a name that is also the name of an existing directory, I renamed it:

```
bundles.Add( new Bundle( "~/js/tinymce" )
                 .Include( "~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
                            "~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js" ) );
```

However, due to the way TinyMCE dynamically loads dependencies (plugin and theme files) I have to make sure all of that is included in the bundle as well:

```
bundles.Add( new Bundle( "~/js/tinymce" )
                 .Include( "~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/autoresize/plugin.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/charmap/plugin.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/code/plugin.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/textcolor/plugin.min.js",
                           "~/Scripts/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js") );
```

This means that if I wanted a new plugin it would require a code change and redeployment of bin files instead of a simple script update. However, the requirement for this application hasn't changed and probably won't any time soon (plus, it's an internal app), so this isn't really a problem.

Finally, TinyMCE also dynamically loads skin files (css, images and fonts). I can fix this by changing the TinyMCE configuration to specify the skin directory:

```
$('.tinymce').tinymce({
    skin_url: '/Scripts/tinymce/skins/lightgray',
    // other stuff...
});
```

I tried creating a bundle for the theme files:

```
bundles.Add( new Bundle( "~/css/tinymce" )
                 .Include( "~/Scripts/tinymce/skins/lightgray/*.css" ) );
```

And changing my configuration like so:

```
$('.tinymce').tinymce({
    skin_url: '/css/tinymce',
    // blah blah blah...
});
```

But, because TinyMCE looks for individual files, this did not work. It threw 404 errors for skin.min.css and content.min.css.

So now I have some of the TinyMCE files bundled, but not all of them. This is at least better than what I had before (separate HTTP requests for every single file).

Comment: using the skin_url: sorted my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your bundle name to something other than an existing location on disk

For example: `Bundle( "~/Scripts/tinymce")` to `Bundle( "~/js/tinymce")`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work because TinyMCE needs to load a bunch of other resources.

Comment: Not too familiar with TinyMCE, but why wouldn't those resources be part of your bundle?

Comment: Kinda. See the answer I posted. I'm not really satisfied with it so let me know if you can think of a way to improve.