# syntax error on safari after bundling code

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, safari, asp.net-bundling

Hi I have JavaScript function that's throwing syntax error on **safari** but the code works in all other browsers (chrome, ff). I am receiving this error only after the inbuild minification process *bundling* of .Net.

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'function'

**Before bundling :**

```
function btnStatus($btn, $status) {

    if ($status) {
        $btn.prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $btn.attr('disabled', true);
    }

    return false;
}
```

**After bundling :**

```
function btnStatus(n, t) { return t ? n.prop("disabled", !1) : n.attr("disabled", !0), !1}
```

Can someone show me the insight of this error!

Comment: What is exactly *before* `function btnStatus(...`?

Comment: it's starting line of file! `function` appends next to the method immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem is not due to `btnStatus` function. it's because of the minification process of ASP.NET on bundling. When I disabled the minification process it works. Honestly I don't understand why safari producing error but not other browsers.

Fortunately disabling minification on bundling is already explain in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14816313/430112) by @Rudi Visser answer.